# Compressing ES5 functions that don't use this into arrow functions

Tags: ecmascript-6, minify, uglifyjs, arrow-functions

While there are plenty of resources related to ES6 arrow functions being transpiled to ES5, there doesn't seem to be much going the other way.

At one point, it looks like [Uglify supported the optimization](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2150). But the current list of compression options (as of uglify-js@3.4) no longer includes arrows.

[The transform looks like it may have been removed?](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2271) Is there a similar minification tool that does this soundly?

Comment: This is not safe to do it anyway, I don't think it's worth it, even if it saves couple of kb. Most weight of your bundle will be libraries anyway.

Comment: Arrows and normal functions have other differences, so swapping them out indiscriminately could potentially break code.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I don't mean indiscriminately. At least working with vanilla JS, the autofixing of https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback is the bar I'd like to clear for a transpiled to JS lang.

Comment: That's the issue though. ESLint only runs on the files of your specific project and you can always turn it off if you don't want it. Assuming you're bundling, Uglify runs across all files in your project, including random stuff in `node_modules` which means just updating a dependency could break your project if they started relying on something that relied on normal functions. That ESLint rule can change the behavior of code, here's an example: https://jsbin.com/bonixob/edit?js,console